# How do I change a string format from 00/00/0000 to 00.00.0000

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, datetime-format, custom-function

I am currently writing a custom function in Google App Scripts. Right now I am struggling. I defined an argument to take input from a date cell and change the format.

e.g 9/16/2010 to 09.16.2010 where a given column has the former date and the function outputs the latter.

The output is a string, but I can't seem to find any information on this specific text editing feature of javascript.

It's also worth mentioning that the date in a given column is based on a form output, I am not calling a specific short date in the code, so rather this is more string manipulation than date formatting

Any help is appreciated.

```js
/**
*Generates a Trip Key
*
*@param DateColumn Date 
*@param SchoolColumn School name
*@param LocationColumn Location
*@customfunction
*/
function GENERATEKEY(DateColumn) {

  var Date = DateColumn       

  const dateStr = Date;
  const dateArr = dateStr.split('/');
  dateArr[0] = ('0' + dateArr[0]).slice(-2);
  dateArr[1] = ('0' + dateArr[1]).slice(-2);

  const DateEdited = dateArr.join('.');

  return neWDateStr; //gives 00.00.0000

  //var Key = Date SchoolColumn "@" LocationColumn




}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a cell format that needs to be applied?

Comment: Does your newly formatted date appear in a separate cell in a different column?

Comment: Get date value and then format it as your wish

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is a built-in object. It should not be used as a variable name.

While `const` is allowed in Google Apps Script, it's not fully supported (it doesn't work as the ECMAScript states). IMHO it's better to use `var` to avoid "confusions".

In Google Sheets, based in the spreadsheet settings, change values entered in supported date-time format into serial numbers and use a number format to display it as date, time, date-time or duration. When a serial number displayed as date, date-time, time or duration is passed to a custom function, Google Apps Script convert it to a Date object.

To return a date formatted use Utilities.formatDate(...) Details in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

Related

- [How to format the date in this Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62586/88163)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use inbuilt [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) function:

```
=TEXT(A2,"mm.dd.yyyy")
```

The reason  your current  script(as provided in one of the previous answers) doesn't work is because the argument `DateColumn` is not of type `String`. You can convert the date object to a specific string and format it accordingly or use inbuilt [`Utilities`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) library.

```
function DOWHATTEXTDOES(dateColumn) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(dateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy.MM.dd")
}
```

#### Essential Reading:

- [Custom function Data type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#data_types)
- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
  "02/05/2009".split('/').join('.');
```

Comment: Note that this is exactly what my solution is as above (just in a single line) - but the reason I did not do this myself was that although the OP stated that the format has the leading "0" in the date and month field - the given example did not and so my solution provuides the leading zero-s to single digit month and day values. Apart from that - your solution is exactly the same as mine. Do not let the attraction of a single line solution distract you from providing a solid and robust solution.

Comment: @gavgrif I see. I wrote it on my phone and at the time your solution hadn't been posted yet. Also, I missed the piece of formatting you alerted me to.

Comment: no probs -  we are often writing solutions at the same time. Also just a suggestion - if you are looking to implement your solution and assume that the leading zero's are always there) - then you could simply to a replace() . - eg - newDateStr = origDateStr.replace('\'g,'.') and not worry about splitting the sting to an array just to rejoin it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

**Get and Set the numberFormat for the active range**

```
Sheet.getRange().setNumberFormat("mm.dd.yyyy");
```

Here's a dialog and function that I use sometimes for playing around with different formats.  I find it a lot easier and quicker that using the spreadsheet functions.

The top function is a dialog that reads and displays the current format for the active range and has a textbox and button for each cell in the in the active range that allows you to set the number format and see the change immediately.

```
function getandSetActiveRangeFormats() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var fA=rg.getNumberFormats();
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Item</th><th>A1 Notation</th><th>Number Format</th><th>Enter Format</th><th>Set Format</th></tr>';
  var item=1;
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  fA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      var txt=Utilities.formatString('<input type="text" id="RC-%s-%s" />',row+i,col+j);
      var btn=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" value="Set Form" onClick="setFormat(%s,%s);" />',row+i,col+j);
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',item++,sh.getRange(row + i,col + j).getA1Notation(),fA[i][j],txt,btn);
    });
  });
  html+='</table><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<script>function setFormat(row,col){var f=document.getElementById("RC-"+row+"-"+col).value;google.script.run.setFormat(row,col,f);}</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString(html));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Display Cell Formats")
}

function setFormat(row,col,format) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(row,col).setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Animation:

[image]